# Woocommerce Change add to cart button link and text after purchase

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have written this code in order to disable add to cart button after the user bought the course (digital product).

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_text', 900, 2 ); // Archive product pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_text', 900, 2 ); // Single product pages
function custom_add_to_cart_text( $button_text, $product ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $button_text = __("click to view Download file", "woocommerce");
        
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Now I want to add a link to my-account/downloads/ page.
Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: "Now I want to add a link to my-account/downloads/ page. Can anyone help me with this." Please elaborate

Comment: @mujuonlys I mean when the users has bought the product the add to cart button functionality changes to a simple link to downloads endpoint of woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

You already changed the Add to cart button text, but you are missing 2 more steps.

**Firstly**, you need to redirect the customer to the Downloads page for such products. This can be done using `woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action` filter - basically this will override the `<form>` action on single product page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', 'custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action' );
function custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action( $action ) {
    global $product;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Redirect customer to 'downloads' page if this product is already purchased
    if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $action = esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) );
    }

    return $action;
}
```

**Secondly**, even though the customer is redirected to the Downloads page, the add to cart event still happens in the background and you need to prevent this. You can utilize the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter and return `false` for already purchased products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 20, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Prevent add to cart event (validation) if this product is already purchased
    if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id ) ) {
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

Tested and works.

---

**EDIT:** This solution only works if AJAX add to cart is disabled in WooCommerce. If it is enabled you need to prevent the event, e.g. by conditionally modifying add to cart button class from `single_add_to_cart_button` to `single_redirect_button`.

Comment: thanks for the great job you have done @KristiánFilo. I tested this code but unfortunately it didn't work. can you check it again please.

Comment: @HamedNajafi sorry, I had a typo in the name of `custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action`, please fix the function name and try again.

Comment: yes, I noticed that, and you just missed a ; after the first addfilter but none of these warnings was the issue. I fixed all the errors and checked it in many ways, but i was not successfull.

Comment: I also tried to return "$action = esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) );" with my first code, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: @HamedNajafi I tested it again. Turned out it does work, but only if the AJAX add to cart for single product page is disabled. If it is enabled, it doesn't work (the product is not added to the cart, but the redirect is not working). A solution would be to conditionaly alter the add to cart button classes (e.g. with jQuery) based on the `wc_customer_bought_product` condition. If you need, I'll try to come up with an example.